# Как называются конструкции вида «глагол + что + инфинитив»?

Tags: синтаксис, терминология, местоимения

Возьмём предложения:

> Скажи что делать.
>
> Подумаем что купить.

1. Это же простое предложение? У такой конструкции есть какое-нибудь особое название?
2. *Что* — это какое местоимение? Или это союз?
3. У Розенталя или Лопатина есть какой-нибудь параграф о таких случаях?

Ответ «Грамоты» № 266309:

> Запятая в подобного рода конструкциях, состоящих из глагола *найти*,
> вопросительно-относительного местоимения или наречия (*кто, что, где,
> куда* и др.) и неопределенной формы другого глагола, не ставится: не
> *нашла что сказать*, *нашли что скрывать*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Эта тема у Розенталя   называется  § 41. **ЦЕЛЬНЫЕ ПО СМЫСЛУ ВЫРАЖЕНИЯ**
   https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

В этом случае  фразеологический оборот не образует придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения и обычно эквивалентен **члену предложения.**

Из примеров Грамоты.ру:  ***не нашла что сказать*** (= нужных слов),  ***нашли что скрывать***  (= тайну, ирон.).  Это  простые предложения,  устойчивый оборот в роли дополнения, запятая не ставится

2. Если такого обобщенного смысла нет, то это **обычное СПП с придаточным изъяснительным:** ***Скажи,  что делать. Подумаем,  что купить***.

Главное предложение (скажи) –  односоставное определенно-личное,  придаточное предложение (что делать) – безличное инфинитивное, ЧТО – союзное слово в роли дополнения.

Примеры:

Отдай мне приказ, и пусть он будет верен. **Скажи, что делать?** [Сергей Лукьяненко. Ночной дозор (1998)]   Вы меня прямо разволновали, сеньор… **Не знаю, что сказать**. [Дина Рубина. (2008-2009)]   ― Скажи, **что купить…** [Галина Щербакова.(2001)]

Comment: Это не фразеологизм, потому что смысл очевиден из частей.

Comment: Фразеологизмы бывают разного вида. Например: https://www.yaklass.ru/materiali?lsnid=498&mode=lesson  Я цитирую Розенталя.

Comment: Тут можно взять любое местоимение и любой инфинитив, так что даже сочетания не получается.

Comment: Можете составлять любые сочетания,  но это будет скорее  обычное придаточное предложение. Фразеологизм должен иметь обобщенный смысл,  и тогда его можно заменить словом-синонимом.